# bokeh html not rendering on company server

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I have a bokeh plot which works perfectly on my vagrant machine...  Here's the bottom of the method which returns the html and some other methods I found which make it work nicely.

However, I get the not-too-helpful `**Override** the getHTML method to insert your own HTML here` exception when I try to view the graph on another machine on my company intranet.

Any guesses as to why this might be happening? I'm not sure if this is related to `spyre` or `bokeh`, my guess is *bokeh*.

What are some possible reasons this isn't rendering on my company's server. The app itself works, I see text, nicely formatted. I have all the required software dependencies. My guess is that there might be something blocking javascript...?

```
def bokeh(self):
    p = figure()
    for col, color in zip(GRAPH_COLUMNS, GRAPH_COLORS):
        #THE NEXT LINE IS THE ONE WHICH DOESN'T COMPLETE.
        p.circle(g.index, g[col], 
                legend = col, 
                fill_color = color,
                line_color = color)
        p.line(g.index, g[col],
            legend = col,
            fill_color = color,
            line_color = color,
            line_dash = "4 4")


.
.
.

   script, div = components(p, INLINE)
    html = "%s\n%s"%(script, div)

    return html

def getCustomJS(self):
    return INLINE.js_raw[0]

def getCustomCSS(self):
    return INLINE.css_raw[0]

app = MyApp()
app.launch(port=9097,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "fill_color" is not being handled correctly as it is not an attribute of figure(). Somehow this gives an error in some versions but not in others.

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell from what I have in one of my apps that seem to work okay. In The line:

> script, div = components(p, INLINE)

I use:

> script, div = components(p, CDN)

Don't know if this will help.